# Updating version number in php file using grunt

Tags: php, node.js, gruntjs

I'm using grunt to compile, minify etc css and javascript which is all working as it should. But as i'm integrating it into an existing php site, for me to see the changes I need to update the version number in the php to clear the cache and the updated CSS to be shown.eg:

```
$nVersion = 20150807;
```

I've looked around but can't find a npm package which will allow me to specify the file and update certainly elements of the file.

Does anyone know of a package like this exists or know another way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else interested I've used grunt-text-replace npm package with the following grunt task:

```
replace: {
        version: {
            src: ['./version.php'],
            dest: './version.php',
        replacements: [{
            from: /^\$nVersion = ([0-9])+/igm, // eg $nVersion = 20150807;
            to: '$nVersion = ' + Date.now() // $nVersion = 1439212970400;
        }]
    }
}
```

And have attached the task to the watcher for any changes to the SCSS, JS files then it updates the version number